# Integration problem NLog with Elasticsearch in .NET Core

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-core, nlog

I am using NLog to write logs to file, which is working fine. Now I want to write logs to Elasticsearch, so I added NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch in nugets package and I configured my Nlog.config file. Unfortunately, I can't see any log information while calling http://localhost:9200/_search

In NLog.config, I added extension and targets for Elasticsearch:

```xml
   <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Extended" />
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch"/>
   </extensions>

<targets>
  <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" 
        name="elastic" 
        layout="${logger} | ${threadid} | ${message}" 
        includeAllProperties="true" 
        uri="http://localhost:9200"/>
 </targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="elastic" />
</rules>
```

I expect Trace type NLog should be written in Elasticsearch. Am I missing something in the config file?

By the way, I checked this doc for parameters: https://github.com/ReactiveMarkets/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch/wiki

Comment: Try removing the line `<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />` from your `<rules>`

Comment: Please check https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Internal-logging.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal  as I mentioned above I also write log in file, just above Nlog configuration I have not added that target parts, that part working fine. Anyway , I also did what you suggested, I comment that part, again not working.

Comment: @Julian I have not find any extra info in your suggested link.

Comment: There should be something in the internal log.

Comment: On error, it's writing to the internal log, see https://github.com/markmcdowell/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch/blob/9c73c15e6929ca2f7c6324aa77a4876b00e72556/src/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch/ElasticSearchTarget.cs#L167-L194

Comment: @Julian , I am also doing internal logging using NLog.  I just want do integration with ElasticSearch. As far as I know, if I successfully integrate, there is no need extra I should do for ES. While I logging , it automatically send to elasticSearch and I can see while calling http://localhost:9200/_search . For detail info , you can see https://damienbod.com/2016/08/20/asp-net-core-logging-with-nlog-and-elasticsearch/

Comment: OK. I hoped for a clear error message. :(

Comment: You got this working as I your newer (and related) question has been answered? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56683912/index-format-change-daily-to-weekly

Comment: @Julian I found my answer for this post , and added below solution. thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just added `BufferingWrapper type` and it worked. Some references to read:

- https://github.com/markmcdowell/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch/blob/master/src/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch.Tests/App.config
- https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/BufferingWrapper-target

Additionally, please check ElasticSearch.Net latest version in NuGet package.

You can find NLog configuration for Elasticsearch below, which is working fine for me:

```xml
<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Extended" />
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch"/>
</extensions>

<target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" name="ElasticSearch"
        flushTimeout="5000">
   <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch"          
          uri="http://localhost:9200" 
          includeAllProperties ="true">
   </target>
 </target>

<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ElasticSearch" />
</rules>
```